# write into database by coldfusion

Tags: database, coldfusion

I'm writing a submit.cfm document. I'm trying to write the users info into a blank new database. 
Here's my code:

```
<cfif ParameterExists(form.submit)>
<cfquery name="AddProfile" datasource="careers_acad_internship">
    INSERT INTO internships
        VALUES (
          '#form.stu_first#', '#form.stu_last#', 
          #form.stu_id#,      '#form.sup_name#', 
          '#form.sup_email#', #form.sup_phone#,
          '#form.emp_name#', '#form.emp_add#',
          '#form.spec_obj#', '#form.spec_duties#',
          '#form.semester#', #form.intern_year#,
          '#form.work_sche#', '#form.digital_sig#')        
</cfquery>
```

But it turns out there's an error. I don't know if it's some syntax errors or else.

The error message is below.

COLUMN 0
ID CFQUERY
LINE 24
RAW_TRACE at cfsubmit2ecfm1505563048.runPage(D:\web\careers\academicinternship\submit.cfm:24)
TEMPLATE D:\web\careers\academicinternship\submit.cfm
TYPE CFML

Thanks,

Comment: What error are you receiving? It's hard to troubleshoot an error without knowing what the error is. Based on the code included, you don't have a closing `<cfif>` tag. `parameterExists` is deprecated as of ColdFusion MX, so if you are using a later version that may be causing you trouble.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual error message that you are receiving.  We will be able to provide a lot more help once that is included.

Comment: COLUMN 0  
ID CFQUERY  
LINE 24  
RAW_TRACE at cfsubmit2ecfm1505563048.runPage(D:\web\careers\academicinternship\submit.cfm:24)  
TEMPLATE D:\web\careers\academicinternship\submit.cfm  
TYPE CFML

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the list of column names to insert the values into
for example:

`INSERT INTO internships (stu_first, stu_last, stu_id, sup_name,sup_email,sup_phone,emp_name,emp_add,sec_obj,spec_duties,semester,intern_year,work.sche,digital_sig)
VALUES('#form.stu_first#','#form.stu_last#',#form.stu_id#,'#form.sup_name#','#form.sup_email#',#form.sup_phone#,'#form.emp_name#', '#form.emp_add#','#form.spec_obj#','#form.spec_duties#','#form.semester#',#form.intern_year#,'#form.work_sche#','#form.digital_sig#')`

Assuming, of course, your column names are the same as your form variable names.

Comment: With many database engines, this is not necessary.  The syntax of the original question is valid as long as the number, type, and order of fields specified in the `VALUES` list is the same as what is specified for the definition of the table.  I consider it best practice to include the list of fields as you suggest, but it is unlikely that this is what was causing the error (which wasn't specified as of this writing, otherwise I'd just diagnose from there).

Answer (score 4):

First, double check your datatypes, I noticed you quoted some variables but not others, make sure the bellow is correct.

```
<cfquery datasource="foobar">
    INSERT INTO internships
        (stu_first,stu_last,stu_id,sup_name,sup_email,sup_phone,emp_name,emp_add,spec_obj,spec_duties,semester,intern_year,work_sche,digital_sig)
    VALUES(
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.stu_first#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.stu_last#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.stu_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.sup_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.sup_email#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.sup_phone#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.emp_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.emp_add#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.spec_obj#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.spec_duties#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.semester#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.intern_year#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.work_sche#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#form.digital_sig#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
    )
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can post the error you're receiving, that will help.

Also, a HUGE suggestion -- use cfqueryparam on your inserted values to prevent SQL injection, for example:

```
<cfqueryparam value="#form.stu_first#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

Double check your `#` signs and your tick marks, not to mention the existence of those variables.  Sometimes I will put a `<cfabort>` before an insert, and with debug output enabled, you can then scroll down and see all of your form variables.  I will then copy/paste those to ensure I spell everything correctly.

Comment: COLUMN 0  
ID CFQUERY  
LINE 24  
RAW_TRACE at cfsubmit2ecfm1505563048.runPage(D:\web\careers\academicinternship\submit.cfm:24)  
TEMPLATE D:\web\careers\academicinternship\submit.cfm  
TYPE CFML

Answer (score 2):

Two things jump out:

1. You should be using `<cfqueryparam>` in your insert statement (and every other query in your application).  This is to prevent SQL injection and also to improve performance slightly.
2. You should explicitly list your columns in your insert statement before your VALUES clause.